# test all combination (c++)

Tags: c++, combinations

I assume this is a classic question but I did not find an answer that fit my problem.
I have two vectors of 'MyObject' and I want to iterate through all possible combination of the elements of the first vector with those of the second one, and treat all cases separatly. (the second vector might have more elements than the first one).
Here is a **pseudo code** of what I am currently doing :

```
select_assignement(vector1, vector2, assignement){
    vector1_memory = copy(vector1);
    vector2_memomry = copy(vector2);

    foreach(element1 in vector1){
        foreach(element2 in vector2){
            assignement[element1] = element2;
            vector1_memory.remove(element1);
            vector2_memory.remove(element2);
            if(vector1_memory.size()>0)
                select_assignement(vector1_memory, vector2_memory, assignement);
            else
                print_assignment(assignment); // Here I finally get one possible assignement
        }
    }
}
```

Here I assume that vector1 is smaller or equal to vector2. So I assign each couple of 'MyObject' between the two vectors and if there are some elements left I do it again recursively. My problem is that I have to copy the vectors each recursion because I can't remove an object of the during a loop on the vector... 
My question is : is it the right way to do that, or am I totally crazy ?

Thanks for your help

**Edit :** the output for two lists `[a,b,c]` and `[1,2,3,4]` would be :

```
assignement : [a1,b2,c3]
assignement : [a1,b2,c4]
 ... 
assignement : [a4,b3,c2]
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing a plain double `for` ? Why the recursion ?

Comment: A double for loop would give me all combination between one element of vector1 with one element of vector2, but not all the combination of the whole set of elements of vector1 with the whole set of elements of vector2. (Or maybe I design this poorly)

Comment: Do you mean concatenating `vec1` and `vec2`, then shuffling the resulting `vec3` ? Or maybe shuffle then concatenate ? I have trouble understanding your goal.

Comment: I mean if got two lists `[a,b,c]` and  `[1,2,3,4]` I don't want as an output : `{[a1],[a2],...[c3],[c4]}` but `{[a1,b2,c3], [a1,b2,c4], ... , [a4,b3,c2]}`

Comment: could you add a simple example to your question with two simple vectors? for example three and two elements?

Comment: So it boils down to choosing `size(vec1)` elements from `vec2` at "random", in any order, and then pairing them with `vec1`'s elements. Heh, that's a bit tricky...

Comment: excatly ! I didn't see it that way but that's it. The problem with doing that randomly is that I need to iterated through all possible combinations (and not leave some).. But I believe there might be a way to do it with some std function.. That might be a much better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think using next_permutation is much better, as you said :

```
void Part::select_assignement(std::vector<MyObject> & vector1, std::vector<MyObject> & vector2 ){
    std::map<MyObject,MyObject> assignement;
    do {
        j++;
        assignement.clear();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vector1.size(); ++i)
            assignement[vector1[i]] = vector2[i];
        treat_this_case(assignement);
    }while(std::next_permutation(vector2.begin(), vector2.end()));
}
```

It seems to me that it does exactly the same thing as before, but in a much easier way.

Comment: The only thing here is that if vector2.size() > vector1.size(), I will get several time the same combination (when I get a permutation outside the range of the assignment)... But it is not a problem in my scenario.
And my tests shows that it seems much faster than the first recursive way.